# Javascript dates: a nightmare

Tags: javascript, date

I understand that dealing with dates, in any environment, could be quite confusing, but I'm in a nightmare with a function that should be a trivial job.
I want to manipulate in different ways some dates, but I get errors or wrong results.
I report hereafter a very simple example made to test the execution; the goal here is to get the current month beginning date, just to show what happens:

```
function DateAdjust() {
var newdate   = new Date();         //1: 2018-12-12T21:00:20.099Z
newdate = newdate.setDate(1);       //2: 1543698020099
newdate=Date(newdate);                  //3: Wed Dec 12 2018 21:01:43 GMT+0000 (Ora standard dell’Europa occidentale)
var d = newdate.getDate();          //4: newdate.getDate is not a function
```

}

4 lines, 3 unexpected results (as shown by Firefox's debugger):
1. the starting date has no day-of-week and no timezone
2. setting the day, result is transformed in milliseconds (why?); I do not know if it is correct.
3. reconverting in string gives the original date, unmodified (why?) but with week day and timezone
4. trying to get the day value an error is thrown (why?)

My environment:
Win 7 32bits SP1
Firefox 63.0.3 (32 bit)
jquery-2.2.4.min.js

I know these questions are boring, but hope someone will find few minutes to clear my mind.

Comment: i recommend looking at [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: 4. forgot `new` before `Date()`

Comment: "No timezone" is incorrect. The `Z` designates UTC.

Comment: 2) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate

Comment: 3) there is no need to do this..... do not override newdate

Comment: I also recommend moment - it's as easy as `moment().startOf('month')`

Comment: I also recommend dayjs, lighter alternative to moment.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do recommend using moment.js

But there are 2 problems with your code:

1-

```
newdate = newdate.setDate(1);
```

setDate mutates newDate in place, and return it in miliseconds, not a new Date object. If you just want to set the date, do this instead:

```
newdate.setDate(1);
```

2-

```
newdate=Date(newdate);
```

Not realy sure why you are trying to get a new Date object, but you need the new, otherwise it will just be a string

```
newdate= new Date(newdate);
```

Fixing problem 1 should eliminate the need for the code of problem 2

Comment: I understand now my errors with object/string. Fixing these function run as expected. As far as moments.js is concerned, I realize that could help, but the very little goal of my function does not justify it, in my opinion. I accepted iagowp answer because is the most concise and easy to understand for a non Englih person.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding line 1, the `Z` at the end is the timezone designation for UTC in ISO 8601 (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC))).

> If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a space. Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset. "09:30 UTC" is therefore represented as "09:30Z" or "0930Z". "14:45:15 UTC" would be "14:45:15Z" or "144515Z".

Regarding line 2 see the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) article on `setDate` (emphasis mine):

> The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the given date (**the `Date` object is also changed in place**).

So you can see the 'correct' behavior you probably expect simply by ignoring the return value:

```
var newdate = new Date(); //1: 2018-12-12T21:00:20.099Z
newdate.setDate(1);       //2: 1543698020099
console.log(newdate);     //3: 2018-12-01T21:00:20.099Z
```

Regarding line 3, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) article on `Date` (emphasis mine):

> *Note*: JavaScript `Date` objects can only be instantiated by calling
>   JavaScript `Date` as a constructor: calling it as a regular function
>   (i.e. without the `new` operator) will **return a string rather than a**
>   **`Date` object**; unlike other JavaScript object types, JavaScript `Date`
>   objects have no literal syntax.

Regarding line 4, the above also explains this error, since `newdate` is now a string rather than a `Date` object.

---

For what it's worth, I agree with the other commenters. JavaScript's date functions are pretty messy compared to many other modern languages. I strongly recommend using a library like [moment](https://momentjs.com/), [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/), or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/). It'll make your life much easier.

Comment: I strongly disagree with "*JavaScript's date functions are pretty messy*". They are very straight forward. The OP's problem is apparent ignorance of the Date constructor and instances, and calling *Date* as a function instead of as a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newdate   = new Date();  // 1
console.log(typeof newdate, newdate); // object Wed Dec 12 2018 23:00:44 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
newdate = newdate.setDate(1); // 2    
console.log(typeof newdate, newdate); //number 1543698085383
newdate=Date(newdate);        //3       
console.log(typeof newdate, newdate);  //string Wed Dec 12 2018 23:04:44 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
var d = newdate.getDate();       // 4
console.log(typeof d, d); //
```

1. Date type is assigned to the object.
2. number is assigned to newdate. which is ticks
3. returns string
4. string.getDate() is not defined, so undefined.

hope it helps.